# How do I customize the Ubuntu panel?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-panel

I want to customize Ubuntu precise. I've deleted the top panel and Applications and moved them to the bottom.

Now what I want is to create a top panel with some application shortcuts such as gedit, terminal, firefox etc.  Please explain the steps.

Comment: Are you using Unity, Unity-2D, gnome shell, or gnome classic?

Comment: just drag and drop?

Comment: gnome classic.I want a permenent setting in the filesystem.not dot files